# Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8): with Rails 4.1 & mysql BLOB datatype

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8

i am using **rails 4.1 with mysql.**

In the database table for a column i have a blob datatype wherein i am saving news paper articles, but while fetching all in index action i am getting below error.

> Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):

i tried many solutions on the net , but not able to resolve the issue.

*** before_save {  self.article = article.encode('utf-8', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => '_')}*** etc..

your help is highly appreciated.. thanks

Comment: Why use a blob column if the data is text ?

Comment: I want to store large amount of data like 5000 words, which i was not able to do with text datatype.

Comment: Hey Frederick thanks for questioning " why ? " :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI .. it is resolved i changed Data type from BLOB to TEXT and it worked.

> BLOB values are treated as binary strings (byte strings). They have no
>   character set, and sorting and comparison are based on the numeric
>   values of the bytes in column values. TEXT values are treated as
>   nonbinary strings (character strings). They have a character set, and
>   values are sorted and compared based on the collation of the character
>   set.

[The BLOB and TEXT Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)